# Is there a way to check of locations are within a specific region in firestore?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I'm implementing an app that checks how long each user is in a specific region. Is there a way for me to implement this as a cloud function within Firestore?

I know that I can save locations as LocationPoint so is there a way to actually check this?

thanks!

Comment: check this out https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately I'm using Firestore and saw this somehwere:
"Sam from the Cloud Firestore team here. As SUPERCILEX said, Cloud Firestore has support for the GeoPoint data type already. We are working hard to bring native geo queries to the product.

Because native geo queries are coming, we will not be porting GeoFire to Cloud Firestore. Instead we will redirect that engineering effort to getting the native queries sooner.

If you need geo queries today and don't want to build your own library, stick with Realtime Database!" :(